# Estimating the multiple input in PROC MIXED

Tags: sas, proc, mixed-mode

I'm looking for something that similar to Proc score (result from proc reg) for estimating the data set.

So far I have something like this.

```
PROC MIXED data = maindata noclprint covtest;
Class ID;
Weight w1;
Model TIME = Age Age*Age / Solution cl residual;
Random Intercept Age Age*Age / sub=ID;
Estimate 'ID1' Intercept 1 Age 10 Age*Age 100 | Intercept 1 Age 10 Age*Age 100/ cl Subject 1;
Estimate 'ID2' Intercept 1 Age 12 Age*Age 144 | Intercept 1 Age 12 Age*Age 144/ cl Subject 0 1;
Estimate 'ID3' Intercept 1 Age 11 Age*Age 121 | Intercept 1 Age 11 Age*Age 121/ cl Subject 0 0 1;
Estimate 'ID4' Intercept 1 Age 15 Age*Age 225 | Intercept 1 Age 15 Age*Age 225/ cl Subject 0 0 0 1;
(. . . You get the point)
run; quit;
```

Here is my estimate data set:

```
ID  Age AgeSq
1   10   100
2   12   144
3   11   121
4   15   225
...
50  9    81
```

My question is there are any other way that is more efficiency than have 50 of these estimate statement.

I tried PROC PLM. The problem with PROC PLM (SCORE(PREDICTED)) is that it doesn't take random effect into an account.(http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/statug/63347/HTML/default/viewer.htm#statug_plm_a0000000126.htm)

Comment: What version of SAS do you have?

Comment: SAS Stat 13.1+ CODE Statement=> http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/statug/67523/HTML/default/viewer.htm#statug_mixed_syntax04.htm

Comment: Just tried CODE statement today. CODE statement have the same problem with proc plm. It doesn't take the random effect into an account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: I hadn't properly read the end of your question regarding `plm`. My apologies, please see below the break for an alternative.

This is not something I've done but I believe you can achieve what you want with [`proc plm`](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/statug/63347/HTML/default/viewer.htm#statug_plm_a0000000115.htm) which can score datasets (among other things) using models produced by `proc mixed`, `proc glm` and others.

The basic approach is to store a binary representation of your model using the [`store` statement](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/statug/67523/HTML/default/viewer.htm#statug_mixed_syntax16.htm):

```
proc mixed;
    ...
    store sasuser.myModel;
run;
```

Then process your new data using `proc plm`:

```
proc plm source = sasuser.mixed;
    ...
    score data = inData out = want;
run;
```

The [user guide](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/statug/63347/HTML/default/viewer.htm#statug_plm_sect002.htm) should help with the [finer points](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/statug/63347/HTML/default/viewer.htm#statug_introcom_a0000003042.htm).

---

There is some more discussion of a similar question with input from Rick Wicklin [here](https://communities.sas.com/message/102872).

---

As a quick and dirty alternative you could use a macro variable to write your estimate `statements`:

```
proc sql;
    select 
        "estimate 'ID" || put(ID, best.) || "' intercept 1 Age " || 
        put(Age, best.) || " Age*Age " || put(Age**2, best.) || 
        " | intercept 1 Age " ||  put(Age, best.) || " Age*Age " || 
        put(Age**2, best.) || " / cl subject" || repeat(" 0", (ID - 1)) || "1;"
    into :estList separated by " " 
    from inEst
    order by ID;
quit;
proc mixed data = maindata noclprint covtest;
    class id;
    weight w1;
    model time = age age*age / solution cl residual;
    random intercept age age*age / sub = id;
    &estList.;
    ods output estimates = want;
quit;
```

Basically you create all the `estimate` statements as strings in an sql query and store them in a macro variable. This approach has its drawbacks:

- The code becomes obfuscated; it's not obvious what's being done. I'd comment code like this heavily to make it very clear to any poor maintainer why you've done this and what it's doing.
- Macro variables have have a finite length (65534 characters). If there is any risk of your variable exceeding this you should split it up (with `call symput` and a `do` loop) and call the lines from  a `%do` loop.

---

Edit: One more option you might want to explore.

In recent releases `proc mixed` and `proc plm` have supported the [`code` statement](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/statug/67523/HTML/default/viewer.htm#statug_mixed_syntax04.htm) which [can be used](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/statug/67523/HTML/default/viewer.htm#statug_introcom_sect013.htm) to output the SAS data step code required to score new observations. If necessary you could use the generated code as a basis and modify it for the analysis you wish to perform.

---

`call symput` skeleton:

```
data _NULL_;
    set inEst nobs = obs;
    length mVar $8.;
    /* Store number of lines in a macro variable */
    if _N_ = 1 then call symput("nVars", obs);

    mVar = "est_" || put(_N_, best.);
    value = *** Code to make estimate statement ***;

    /* Create a new macro variable for each line */
    call symput(mVar, value);
run;

%macro temp;
    *** Code ***;
    %do i = 1 %to &nVars.;
         &&est_&i.
    %end;
    *** Code ***;
%mend temp;
%temp;
```

Answer (score 0):

"Macro variables have have a finite length (65534 characters). If there is any risk of your variable exceeding this you should split it up (with call symput and a do loop) and call the lines from a %do loop."

Another option is to have your list for estimates set as a separate code file and use %include  This is also useful for massive variable lists or repeating code blocks that don't require parameters.